# Where safes Logic Pro X the "validation" file from Plug-Ins?

Tags: macos, validation, logic

i search the file where Logic safes Plugin XYZ is valid Plugin SDF is invalid etc... 
It must be anywhere in the System Library folder but i can't find it.

Also a program where i can protocol the file accesses from a program could help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
Logic safes that in the Component file of the Plugin.